# Parse the received message from the server

Tags: c#, server

The problem I'm having is parsing the bytes I'm reading through the server to the client's interface and show them the message received.

The general idea was to send a message, the message goes to the server and then send back the message to all the clients that are connected to the chatroom.

But what really happens is that when I enter the chat room a message appears with ">>IgnUsername" to mark that a new user has entered the chat.

And when I try to send a message such as "Hello" the server receives the messages correctly but when it's time to send back the message to the users what it appears on the screen is ">>IgnUsername". Which is the original message.
I'm not even sure that this is the only faulty extract of code to actually fix the issue I'm having.

```
conn.server.BeginReceive(dat, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(recibiendoF), so);

if (//Something has been received)
{
    mensajenuevo = msjerecibidoF(dat);
}
```

This is the callback

```
public void recibiendoF(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        StateObject so = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        conn.server = so.workSocket;

        int bytesRead = conn.server.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string mensajote = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mensajenuevo);
            if (textBox_curMsg.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                this.textBox_curMsg.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    textBox_curMsg.Text = mensajote;
                });
            }
            else
                textBox_curMsg.Text = mensajote;
            //recibemsje();
        }
        else
        {
            if (so.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                string response = so.sb.ToString();
            }
            //recibemsje();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

And this is the function I wanted to use before using the callback

```
public byte[] msjerecibidoF(byte[] msej)
{
    byte[] mensajeiro = new byte[1024];
    mensajeiro = msej;
    mensajenuevo = msej;
    return mensajeiro;
}
```

Comment: Yoou will need to show a lot more code than that, the code doesn't show where/how/what it is sending back or anything. Please read the FAQ regarding an [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added the callback and the function to use before the callback. The problem is that I really can't select the bit that I'm having problems. I'll try to make it as compact as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.server.BeginReceive(dat, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(recibiendoF), so);

if (//Something has been received)

                {
                    mensajenuevo = msjerecibidoF(dat);
                }
```

This is not how it will work. You are using asyn receive method which returns immediately. The callback is what is called when the actual receive happens. Your method `msjerecibidoF(dat);` will be passed an empty `dat` or and older data.

Also, at the end of `public void recibiendoF(IAsyncResult ar)` you will have to call `onn.server.BeginReceive` again to receive next message.

Because you have posted part of codes, this is the best I can answer. Fix these and than see...